# HTML Button control

Tags: html, button

I am developing one `MVC` project and in my view page I have to show `three HTML button controls in the same row`.

If I use `<div>` then it is not showing in the same line

Please let me know what is the best way to design buttons with the same look and feel and also display all of them in same row.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. If you want a button, then use a button. If you want to influence how they look, use CSS. I've no idea why you would consider using a div when you want a button. I've no idea what look and feel you want the buttons to have so can't suggest what CSS you might use. Your question might be clearer if you provided a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

You could be do in following way if you are using bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button id="btnsubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button id="btnreset" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
```